# Ошибка 429 Instagram API

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instagram-api

У меня есть сайт, где размещены публикации из Instagram при использовании JS-плагина Instafeed.
Но почему-то Instagram API выдает ошибку 429.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: 429 скорее всего большое количество запросов в час

Comment: [429 - too many requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)